# iTunes Connect - App Store Territories

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm about to release an iOS app through iTunes Connect. In "my apps" -> "pricing and availability" -> "Availability" i can edit the territories my app will be available in.

**Are there territories defines as the place an app can be downloaded from, or what country store the user is connected to?**

---

**Example:**

I'm from Denmark, my apple-id is setup to danish store. If i go to another country, say UK, will i be able to download an app that only available in UK-"territory"?

Comment: pricing and availability is no longer an option there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you choose all territories, your app will be available for download (or purchase) worldwide.

You should untick any of those countries if you believe you will violate their laws (such as encryption, data collection, etc.).

Comment: So if I only choose one territory, will my app only be available to users connected to that specific store, or also foreign tourist traveling in that territory?

Comment: Thats correct. Whatever is TICKED in the TERRITORIES settings, those countries will be able to download your app.

Comment: That's not correct. The availability refers to stores, not physical location, eg if your app is available in UK and your Store is Denmark, you won't be able to download the app, wherever you are in the World.